# chmod File Type "s"

Tags: unix, chmod

I have a file and I see it in the system

> ls -la 
>  srwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Apr  7 08:07 ssh-server

But I'm not able to view, copy, move or edit it

> cp ssh-serve /tmp/ 
> cp: cannot open 'ssh-server' for reading: No such device or address

I notice that there's an "s" in the file type, at the very beginning of the permission. 
**s**rwxr-xr-x 1 root root 0 Apr  7 08:07 ssh-server

Can I chmod the "s" to a "-" for this file??

Answer (score 1):

It's a socket, which means that there is a process, using this file. As a result, when you modify or delete it, that process might not be working anymore.

Comment: Just a nit, but you don't have to put "file" in quotes. Sockets are files, as far as the file system is concerned. You can distinguish sockets from *regular* files instead.

Comment: I'm trying to install an application, it should automatically create this "socket" file but it did not.  Is there a way for me to create a socket file?